# Not able to call one Spring REST controller from another with JSON payload

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I call one spring REST controller from another whereby passing in the required injections?

**ProtectPanController.java (Actual Rest controller doing the work)**

```
@RestController
public class ProtectPanController {

    private ProtectPanService protectPanService;

    public ProtectPanController(ProtectPanService protectPanService) {
      this.protectPanService = protectPanService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/pan/protect", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> testPostMethod(@RequestBody ProtectPan protectPan) {
        ResponseEntity response = protectPanService.sendProtectPanRequest(protectPan);
        return response;
    }

}
```

**WORKS (Rest URL: `http://localhost:9090/hosted-payments-webapp-1.0.0/pan/protect`)**

Payload:

```
{
    "paymentAccountNumber": "4111111111111111",
    "tenderClass": "CreditCard"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "token": "4111110PASeK1111"
}
```

**Pan3dsLookupController.java (this controller calls above controller)**

```
@RestController
public class Pan3dsLookupController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/pan/3dslookup"})
    public String doProtectPanAndCmpiLookup(@RequestBody ProtectPanCmpiLookup protectPanCmpiLookup) {
        ProtectPan protectPan = protectPanCmpiLookup.getProtectPan();
        return "forward:/pan/protect";
    }

}
```

**ProtectPanCmpiLookup.java (a wrapper around the actual object)**

```
public class ProtectPanCmpiLookup {

    private ProtectPan protectPan;

    public ProtectPan getProtectPan() {
        return protectPan;
    }

    public void setProtectPan(ProtectPan protectPan) {
        this.protectPan = protectPan;
    }

}
```

**DOES NOT WORK !! (Rest URL: `http://localhost:9090/hosted-payments-webapp-1.0.0/pan/3dslookup`)**

Payload:

```
{
    "protectPan": {
      "paymentAccountNumber": "4111111111111111",
      "tenderClass": "CreditCard"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
forward:/pan/protect
```

Comment: Did you try `redirect:/pan/protect`?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that but no success. I am getting "redirect:/pan/protect" as the response now.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code :

```
return "forward:/pan/protect";
```

works this way and give you that text:

```
forward:/pan/protect
```

is that you use *RestController* and response body of your method is String type:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/pan/3dslookup"})
public String <---
```

> @RestController is a stereotype annotation that combines @ResponseBody
>   and @Controller.

You have to return a ModelAndView object:

```
return new ModelAndView("forward:/pan/protect", modelName, modelObject)
```

Check [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/56867-invoking-a-second-controller) post for more info